# Springboot maven war works on local weblogic 12.2.1.2 but not on other system

Tags: maven, spring-boot, weblogic12c

I developed an application using maven in eclipse oxygen. It uses spring boot 2.1.6. It is working on my local weblogic 12.2.1.3 if  wls:prefer-application-packages is enabled. But not on other systems.Tried different combinations of weblogic.xml.This code does not work in weblogic.

```
 <wls:container-descriptor>
                    <wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>true</wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>
                </wls:container-descriptor>
            The following works locally but not on other systems.
            <wls:container-descriptor>
             <wls:prefer-application-packages>
                        <wls:package-name>org.slf4j.*</wls:package-name>
                        <wls:package-name>org.springframework.*</wls:package-name>
                        <wls:package-name>org.hibernate.*</wls:package-name>
                        <wls:package-name>javax.validation.*</wls:package-name>
                        <wls:package-name>javax.validation.spi.*</wls:package-name>
                    </wls:prefer-application-packages>
                </wls:container-descriptor>
            Error:
            An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

                org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.config.ValidationBootstrapParameters.<init>(ValidationBootstrapParameters.java:63)

            The following method did not exist:

                javax.validation.BootstrapConfiguration.getClockProviderClassName()Ljava/lang/String;

            The method's class, javax.validation.BootstrapConfiguration, is available from the following locations:

                zip:C:/wls12213/user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp/_WL_user/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/vluesa/war/WEB-INF/lib/validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar!/javax/validation/BootstrapConfiguration.class
                jar:file:/C:/wls12213/oracle_common/modules/javax.validation.jar!/javax/validation/BootstrapConfiguration.class

            It was loaded from the following location:

                file:/C:/wls12213/oracle_common/modules/javax.validation.jar

            The war file which is currently generated through pom.xml should work on all weblogic server at least with the same version.
```

Comment: This smells like you need to investigate the dependencies that are deployed as part of the application, as the error seems to indicate version mismatches. There may be some outdated dependencies in there that should not be deployed with the application.

Answer (score 0):

Yoy can not use both these tags at the same time.

```
<wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>true</wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>

<wls:prefer-application-packages>
```

Choose one or the other.

Also when I tested this, I only got the

```
<wls:prefer-application-packages>
```

to work on a standalone server. But did not do a thorough work since I got it to work with the mentioned tag.

[Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e21049/weblogic_xml.htm#WBAPP663)